# javascript play sound too slow start

Tags: javascript, audio, playback, performance

I'm using this to play sounds:

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = 
       "<embed src='"+soundfile+"' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' />";
}
```

And it is **sooo desperatly sloooowwwww to start!!!**

My target is to play a short "chck" when the mouse hover a thumbnail, and when I have 10 thumbnails close to eachother, I want to hear: "chck-chck-chck...."

But not "................../.................chck......../.......chck........./.........."

Admitedly the 1st time the sound file have to be loaded from the server, but after?
It is STILL slow to start.

Of course, I would like a cross-browsers solution.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `emebed` tag on your page like any other element, then use JavaScript to play the sound.

```
<embed src="success.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">

document.getElementById("sound1").play();
```

http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play4.htm